# SOAP service in Django with soaplib

Tags: django, soap

Hi I am looking to create a SOAP service within my Django App, but have come across a few hitches.
Firstly I have been able to successfully follow the soaplib Hello World tutorial (google "soaplib hello world" since I only can use 1 hyperlink as this is my first question) which uses a CheryPy WSGI server to run the service, and the soaplib client to initiate a SOAP request.

I am having trouble converting that into a service within Django through following [this djangosnippets snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/979/). Currently I am using the Django development server.

Viewing `http://localhost:8000/hello_world/` in the browser or making a SOAP request using the soaplib client returns a Django error page with the error:

> `Tried hello_world_service in module foo.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'hello_world_service'`

Obviously `urls.py` is matching correctly, but according to that django snippet I linked to, there shouldn't be a view `hello_world_service`.

I feel I am missing the last step and any knowledge would be really helpful.

Thanks, Marcus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the snippet you link to, the bottom of your `views.py` file should contain the following line:

```
hello_world_service = HelloWorldService()
```

This maps an instance of the `HelloWorldService` class onto the name `hello_world_service`, for use in your `urls.py` file.

If that line is included, then there will indeed be a view with that name - so the URL Dispatcher should be able to find it.

Hope that does it,

Rob

Comment: Thanks rob, that was exactly the problem, I can now make SOAP requests to Django.